# Method to make themes in vscode conditional

Tags: json, visual-studio-code

I use bracket pair colorizer. Is it possible that the bracket pair settings can be modified if the theme is (for example) monokai?
Ik its a json file and json files dont accept if statements, otherwise id write:

```
if "theme" == "monokai" {
  bracket-pair-colorizer-2.colors: [
    "red",
    "green",
    "blue"
  ]
}, else {...}
```

Is there any way to make this reality?

Edit:
I tried setting `editor.tokenColorCustomizations`'s `brackets` option to a list, and string, then tried that with `parenthesis`, and `bracket`, but it simply said that it cannot do that

Comment: you can customize the colors based on theme: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/themes#_customizing-a-color-theme

Comment: use the build-in bracket-pair-coloring, you can customize it by theme

Comment: No... it says that brackets, bracket and parenthesis arent allowed properties

Comment: Who says: `No` to bracket colors, what do you try, edit your question

Comment: the bracket colors are different for `Light+` and `Dark+`, so they are themable, syntax or semantic. there are 6 pairs of FG and BG colors you can set in a Theme

Comment: Youd need to write an extension using the VSCode API. You would want to use the following method `vscode.workspace.getConfiguration()` (please note, you can'e just type a configuration into the method and return it, you have to specify a scope in adition to the settings ID). You will also have to use the `onDidChangeConfiguration` event to change to setting when the theme changed. Here are the links to the docs https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#workspace.workspaceFoldersobject https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#WorkspaceConfiguration

Comment: I've wrote extensions like the one your talking about. I wrote an extension that changed the values assigned to `"editor.ruler": [ ]` when ever the value assigned to  `wordWrapColumn` changed. I can honestly say, it wasn't worth the amount of time that it took to write. It was, however, a great learning experience.